# Проблема с отображением изображений на Github Pages

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

Создал как обычно проект , решил выгрузить на хостинг но возникла проблема с отображением изображения, отображает значение alt.

Репозиторий:

image

> 133.jpg

index.html

style.css

```
<div class="img1">
<img src="../image/133.jpg" alt="Тим Бернерс-Ли">
</div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте вместо двух точек одну. (`./image/133.jpg`)

Comment: Ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зашёл в настройки репозитория Settings -> Pages и в Source изменил /(root) на /docs , теперь картинки отображает.